# Was One ever "romantically" involved with Daniel?

Tags: namesake

According to some Namesake comic fans, the [following conversation](http://namesakecomic.com/comic/dismissed) between Emma Sr. and One suggests that he had been involved with Daniel Crewe at some point:

[image]

On the other hand, One [found and raised Daniel](http://namesakecomic.com/comic/the-boy-in-the-frozen-cave):

[image]

It would be little weird if he'd been romantically involved with him, given that. That said, while I doubt One really "loves" anyone, emotional abuse and manipulation are definitely in his vocabulary.

Was there ever any romantic relationship (however one-sided) between One and Daniel?

Comment: I doubt it. More likely an "adopted father/son" relationship.